# If a range of cells all equal "true" then it will return a content-filled cell from another sheet, into a 3rd sheet

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I would like to make a formula, that states that if a range of cells all equal "true" then it will return a content-filled cell from another sheet, into a 3rd sheet.

Sorry, if that is a terrible explanation.

Basically, i have a Screen Processing sheet with check-boxes on one sheet, which return a true or false input on a second sheet, if they have been clicked or not.

On the same sheet as that, there is a big merged cell with some content already in it.

So on a 3rd sheet, i want to be able to write a formula that basically says.

IF Cells A14-A17 are all true, then in the 3rd sheet in A1 show the content from the 2nd sheet cell K1-16 to V1-16 (merged cell)

I'm happy to clarify any questions you may have, because this appears to be as thick as mud, i'm not great at if/else, print statements, etc.

Thanks for your time and patience. Great community here.

Answer (score 0):

K
If I have read your description correctly - this should do you:
You use a countif to find out if there are any FALSE answers in the range, if there are - it puts in blank (you can easily change this), otherwise it refers to A1 in sheet two.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A14:A16,FALSE)>1,"",Sheet2!K1)
```

Hope this helps